# Can I use Xuggler to encode video/audio to a byte array?

Tags: java, video-encoding

It seems all methods expect either files or urls. I see some methods that work with OutputStream, but I haven't managed to open an IContainer using one of those methods; I always get an invalid return value.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own IURLProtocolHandler interface and pass to IContainer.open(...) to open any type of media type you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731806/how-to-write-to-an-outputstream-using-xuggler/23941046#23941046) I posted on another question to write to an `OutputStream` (which could easily be a `ByteArrayOutputStream`).

This gist of it would be to use `com.xuggle.xuggler.io.XugglerIO` to map from an `OutputStream` to a special kind of file URL so that FFMPEG can access the stream.

```
IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(XugglerIO.map(outputStream));
```

Keep in mind that you'll now have to manually set your format (because it can't detect it from the filename). For example:

```
IContainerFormat containerFormat = IContainerFormat.make();
containerFormat.setOutputFormat("ogg", null, "application/ogg");
writer.getContainer().setFormat(containerFormat);
```