# How to write to an outputStream using xuggler?

Tags: java, outputstream, xuggle, xuggler

So I'm trying to write my encoded buffered image to an output stream but I can't get any data to come through on the stream...  Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and why I can't see any output?

I would expect that when I call the write.encodeVideo method that it encode's video into my ByteArrayOutputStream... is that assumption wrong?

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   
// video parameters
final int videoStreamIndex = 0;
final int videoStreamId = 0;
final long frameRate = DEFAULT_TIME_UNIT.convert(15, MILLISECONDS);
final int width = 512;
final int height = 254;
long nextFrameTime = 0;

// create a media writer and specify the output file
final IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter("aaa.ogg");
   
IContainer ic = writer.getContainer();
ic.open(outputStream, writer.getContainer().getContainerFormat(), true, false);

ICodec codec = ICodec.guessEncodingCodec(null, null,"aaa.ogg", null, ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO);

// add the video stream
writer.addVideoStream(videoStreamIndex, videoStreamId, codec, width, height);

BufferedImage img = null;
try
{
  img = ImageIO.read(new File("/data/aaa.png"));
}
catch (final IOException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
   
for(int yy =0; yy < 2048-height; yy=yy+8)
{
  nextFrameTime++;
  BufferedImage frame = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
  frame = img.getSubimage(0, yy, width, height);
  BufferedImage frame2 = convertToType(frame, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

  //encode the video
  writer.encodeVideo(videoStreamIndex, frame2, nextFrameTime, DEFAULT_TIME_UNIT);
     
  nextFrameTime += frameRate;
}
   
writer.close();
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

Comment: did you figure out the answer?

Comment: I don't think I did? Sorry

Comment: @PhaniRahul I have submitted an answer if you're still looking to encode to an OutputStream.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the way you are creating the `IMediaWriter` is incorrect. You don't want to open the writer's container yourself either. When you are using an `OutputStream` instead of a file you can do it by using the `com.xuggle.xuggler.io.XugglerIO` mapper like this:

```
// create a media writer and specify the output stream
final IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(XugglerIO.map(outputStream));

// manually set the container format (because it can't detect it by filename anymore)
IContainerFormat containerFormat = IContainerFormat.make();
containerFormat.setOutputFormat("ogg", null, "application/ogg");
mWriter.getContainer().setFormat(containerFormat);

// add the video stream
writer.addVideoStream(videoStreamIndex, videoStreamId, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_THEORA, width, height);
```

Keep in mind that if you are trying to create a format that has to be able to "seek" within the output bytes as part of it's creation process (e.g. .mov), then it won't work with a simple `OutputStream` as I have shown. You would have to write to a file instead of an `OutputStream`.