# Xuggler write and read video via H.264 to/from Sockets

Tags: sockets, stream, lan, xuggler, xuggle

I want to be able to send BufferedImages generated from my java program over the local network in real time, some my second application can show them.

I have been looking through a lot of websites over the last 2 days but I wasn't able to find anything. Only thing I found was this: 
[Can I use Xuggler to encode video/audio to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736309/can-i-use-xuggler-to-encode-video-audio-to-a-byte-array)

I tried implementing the URLHandler but problem is, MediaWriter still wants an URL and as soon as I add a VideoStream, it opens the container a second time with the url and then in crashes.

I hope you can help me and thanks in advance.

Code I have right now:

```
val clientSocket = serverSocket.accept()
connectedClients.add(clientSocket)
val container = IContainer.make()
val writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter("localhost", container)
          container.open(VTURLProtocolHandler(clientSocket.getOutputStream()), IContainer.Type.WRITE, IContainerFormat.make())
writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_H264, width, height)
```